# how to integrate the third party SDK consist of .a files with the cocoa pods

Tags: cocoapods

[image]

There is a the third party SDK which consist of .a files and some .h files.when I use the cocoa pods ,how to integrate the linker library. I tried to write something like that `s.framwork ='..'` into the `podfile`,but it did not work when I update the pod.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  'vendored_libraries' option in cocoapods.
https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_libraries

s.vendored_libraries = 'somelib.a', 'someotherlib.a'

Comment: I have already used the methods.but when I updated the pod spec, it was not validate.except that, what should I do ?Need to set the search path?

Comment: please, post your current podspec and errors you get upon validation